# How can I check cells for number series?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, formatting, find, worksheet-function

I have a bit of a problem evaluating an excel cell. Example:

```
          M   M   M   M   M   M   M   M   M   
          1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
2;5;7
1;9
3;5;7;9
```

I have a number of excel cells which contain numbers (months). In the first column I have a series of numbers. I want to use conditional formatting to color the corresponding cells in the right columns. If correctly colored I would get something like this:

```
          M   M   M   M   M   M   M   M   M   
          1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
2;5;7         X           X       X
1;9       X                               X
3;5;7;9           X       X       X       X
```

The formula I have now is this:

```
IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(L$22;$K23));$H23;"")
```

but the problem is that cells are colored too which contain part of a number. If I enter 10;15 as input I get this:

```
          M   M   M   M   M   M   M   M   M   M   M   M   M   M   M
          1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15
10;15     X               X                   X                   X
```

because 1 and 5 are found too. I only want column 10 and 15 to be marked. How can I change the formula or the input?

Answer (score 0):

Tampering with your input data may be a 'cheat' - but perhaps easiest! I'd add a semi colon at the start and end of your input data and then use

`=FIND(";"&L$22&";",$K23)>0`

though I think you would have to replace the comma in this formula with a semi colon also.

Comment: No need to change the source data.  Use `=FIND(";"&L$22&";",";"&$K23&";")>0` (or in the local of the OP `=FIND(";"&L$22&";";";"&$K23&";")>0`)

Answer (score 0):

I found some VBA-function which I changed to this and it works:

```
Function CHECK_INTERVALL(str, colmonth, sepChar)

Dim months As Variant
months = Split(str, sepChar)
Dim i As Integer

CHECK_INTERVALL = False

For i = LBound(months) To UBound(months)
        If CInt(colmonth) = CInt(months(i)) Then
            CHECK_INTERVALL = True
        End If
Next i

End Function
```

If the current month is in the list I get true and the conditional formatting colors the cell.